# How to not allow let users create passwords with space using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm beginner to Ruby On Rails and I tried to do registration (name,email,password, confirming password) on my site (localhost) with restrictions like password can't be blank, password is at least 6 symbols long and password can't be like only spaces (" "). Then I want to let users edit these attributes but if they change it I want to make them write name and mail again but not password ( these 2 first are necessary, if they dont want to change it they leave them up, password is not necessarry so i want to make it blank, thats why in this code i use allow_blank: true)

```
# app/models/user.rb
.
. 
.

has_secure_password

validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true
```

If I do it, users can register with spaces (" ") and it even allows them to break the rule with min 6 symbol ( users can do password like this: " " and I don't want this) so that's the problem.

But when I don't use allow_blank:true, when users want to edit their attributes they need to write again password ( I want to make them write only name and email but password can be left blank and it won't be changed then).

What should I do ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okey I found the answer: instead of allow_blank: true I should have used allow_nil: true.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression, through the `without` option of `validates_format_of`.

```
validates :password,  presence: true,
  length: { minimum: 6 },
  format: { without: /\s/, message: "spaces not allowed" }
```

Comment: I tried it but without allow_blank: true it doesn't help me because when I'm not using allow_blank: true it already forbids using space, but when I'm using allow_blank: true with your code above it doesn't word, still spaces are allowed.